# How to check the delimiter (data separator) in between data strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a SQL script to check the delimiter in between data strings in SQL column. This column stores data strings in following format:

```
ODC-2016-111-824035,ODC-2003-283-125666
```

Generally it should be a comma, I wanted to check if there are any other inappropriate delimiters (separators) such as colons (`:`), semi-colons (`;`), dashes (`-`, `\`, `/`), spaces etc.

Still trying but couldn't find anything useful yet...

There are multiple data strings in a column, and they should be separated by only a comma (`,`) as shown below:

```
ODC-2016-737-733488,ODC-2011-918-286353,ODC-2016-111-824035,ODC-2003-283-125666
```

But sometimes there are some inappropriate delimiters such as colons (`:`), semi-colons (`;`), dashes (`-`, `\`, `/`), spaces etc. - like this:

```
ODC-2016-737-733488-ODC-2011-918-286353;ODC-2016-111-824035:ODC-2003-283-125666
```

Comment: Have a look at how regex works : https://study.com/academy/lesson/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-databases-implementation-use.html

Answer (score 0):

- Academic and clean way to achieve this is by using **REGEX** based query, syntax of which varies from database to database.
- An easier (& brute-force if you will) solution will be to utilize CHARINDEX (or equivalent) function with nested CASE statements.

For SQL Server, regex based solution could be like following

```
with a as (
    select 'ODC-2016-737-733488,ODC-2011-918-286353,ODC-2016-111-824035,ODC-2003-283-125666' phrase
) 
select case count(*) when 0 then 'OK' else 'Special / Undesired character(s) present' end
from a where phrase like '%[,-;]%' -- add all special / undersired characters between []
```

The CHARINDEX based solution will be something like following

```
SELECT 
CASE CHARINDEX(',', 'ODC-2016-737-733488,ODC-2011-918-286353,ODC-2016-111-824035,ODC-2003-283-125666')
WHEN 0 THEN CASE CHARINDEX('-', 'ODC-2016-737-733488,ODC-2011-918-286353,ODC-2016-111-824035,ODC-2003-283-125666')
            WHEN 0 THEN 'OK'  -- you can nest case to capture other characters if you wish
            ELSE 'TEXT HAS -'            
            END    
ELSE 'TEXT HAS ,'
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am still in early stages of learning SQL so I would greatly appreciate if you could help me to add this to my select statement. 
There are thousands of data rows in this column so I am little confuse how can I apply this to it. The format should be:
ODC-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXX
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You have not shown your select statement and from your description the ask is not clear at all. Could you describe the table, supply some sample data and describe what the query should return?